# how to make youtube iframe background "black" on fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube

i searched a lot about "how to make the background of youtube iframe black when the video on fullscreen instead of white"

for example this is my youtube iframe

```
<iframe width="100%" height="45%" 
        [src]="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FyBeA6ct7F0?background=0&autoplay=1&controls=1&showinfo=&autohide=1" 
        frameborder="0" 
        webkitallowfullscreen 
        mozallowfullscreen 
        allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

I checked this way also but no luck

```
<iframe width="100%" height="45%" style="background:#000; background-color:#000;" 
        [src]="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FyBeA6ct7F0?background=0&autoplay=1&controls=1&showinfo=&autohide=1" 
        frameborder="0" 
        webkitallowfullscreen 
        mozallowfullscreen 
        allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Comment: Try background-color:black !important;"

Comment: YouTube IFRAMEs always have a black background. Are you sure your IFRAME is the correct size?

Comment: i think because i use iframe with web app so the problem only happens on the mobile.

Comment: an other point, when i disabled the controls by "controls=0" then the video shows in black background.. i don't know why and how but i'm still trying to solve this issue